# How to write negations.Am I right?

Tags: logic

$1)$For all $ ∈ \mathbb{R}$ , $\sqrt{2}$ is an irrational number.

$2)$For any integers $$ and $$ , where $ ≠ 1$ , either $$ is not a factor
of $$ or $$ is not a factor of $ + 1$.

$3)$For any positive integer; either  is a square number, is a prime
number or $$ is a factor of $( − 1)!$.

---

$1)$Exists such $ ∈ \mathbb{R}$ that $\sqrt{2}$ is a rational number.

$2)$Exist such a and b, where $ ≠ 1$, $$ is  a factor
of $$ and $$ is  a factor of $ + 1$.

$3)$exists such positive integer; $$ is not  a square number, is not a prime
number and $$ is not  a factor of $( − 1)!$

Comment: Apart from the use of "such" (I would prefer "a/an"), the second 1), 2) and 3) look much like negations of the first 1), 2) and 3)

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is correct but the wording needs some polish.

For example for the first one I would say:

There exists a real number $x$ such that $x\sqrt 2$ is a rational number.